# How can i differentiate neuron from perceptron?

Tags: machine-learning, neural-network, perceptron

Conceptually, people talk both are different. There has been a confusion still. Let me summarize what i understood, please educate me. There is a tiny differentiating factor between these two.

1) A tiny change in the weight/bias of a particular perceptron would drastically make other perceptrons behave differently, thought the changed perceptron is intented to perform correctly?

2) A Small change in perceptron can produce different output.

3) With said above, sigmoid neuron is one good example that makes tiny changes in the output with respect to tiny weight/bias changes.

4) Perceptron outputs either 0 or 1, whereas neuron ( ex: sigmoid neuron) can produce the values in between 0-1. 
Is my understanding is correct?. Or, is it totally dump?

Comment: I completely agree with -1. However if u provide details of down voting reason, i also would gain experience from you. That is what SO is for i guess.

Answer (score 0):

A perceptron is a *neural network architecture type*; a regular, layered, feed forward neural network.

A neural network consists of neurons - neurons have activation functions and a bias. Neurons are connected to each other with weights.

Thus, **a perceptron *contains* neurons.**

> 1) A tiny change in the weight/bias of a particular perceptron would drastically make other perceptrons behave differently, thought the changed perceptron is intented to perform correctly?

No. A perceptron is a neural network on its own, it has no effect on other neural networks.

> 2) A Small change in perceptron can produce different output.

Yes, that's possible. But it should be `A Small change in perceptron input can produce different output.`

> 4) Perceptron outputs either 0 or 1, whereas neuron ( ex: sigmoid neuron) can produce the values in between 0-1. Is my understanding is correct?. Or, is it totally dump?

Mothern perceptrons output values between 0 and 1 as well.

Comment: While naming conventions evolved a lot over time, I believe that OP asks about Rosenblatt's perceptron (the original one, from the 50s) that is not really a "layered" network or even a "network" at all, but rather (using modern naming convention) a single, **thresholded** neuron.